# Remove background sound from sing along recording

Tags: noise-reduction, isolation

I was singing along to a song and then I recorded myself.

Now I just want to isolate the sound of my own voice and remove the original sound from the singer.

Is it possible to do it in any way? What if I supply only the original song, is it possible to use that as a template to remove the original singer?
Thanks

Comment: Hmm… the second answer made me think again… do you mean you have a karaoke track with a vocal on, plus the bare karoke? ..or do you mean you have a regular 'record' with original vocal & your own recorded on top of it? From the first you can remove the track, leaving your vocal [see my answer] for the other, there's nothing at all you can do [see Kurt's answer].

Comment: didn't want to mention it.... :-)

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, you could try to use some kind of a statistical method. I believe that you could give Independent Component Analysis (ICA) a chance. I am not sure you would get any results out of it but it seems like a good candidate when it comes to (Blind) Source Separation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no. You layered your voice on top of an existing vocal, and they occupy the same frequency range, pan (left-right) location, etc. No filtering, phase flipping or incantations I'm aware of could remove the original recorded voice from underneath yours.

Consider this first recording a practice run-through. Buy a karaoke backing track of the tune you want to record and use that. Alternatively, you can remove the vocal from the original recording (*mostly*) to show the world how it should have been sung.

Comment: ok thank you ! I guess it cant be done.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, if the two audio files are identical other than the added vocal, then you should be able to set them side by side in something like [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org).

If you can align them to sample-accuracy, then you can [Phase invert](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/invert.html) one of the tracks, which will cancel out all the audio except the vocal.

Comment: haha i see, but what if one is slightly softer than the other, then its impossible?

Comment: Volume is irrelevant really. You need to answer the question in my comment above.